# Execution of a Postgresql query using JDBC taking much more time compared to execution of query in pgadmin

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a stored procedure, with an argument(Parameter)

Let us call it `x`.

When I run,

```
select * from x('myParameter')
```

It completes in 4 minutes.

Now I try to execute the same stored prcedure in java as follows:-

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from x('myParameter')");
org.postgresql.PGStatement pgstmt = (org.postgresql.PGStatement)statement;
pgstmt.setPrepareThreshold(1);
boolean usingServerPrepare = pgstmt.isUseServerPrepare();
System.out.println(usingServerPrepare);
statement.execute();
```

This takes approximately 26 hours to complete.

I was initially trying without `pgstmt.setPrepareThreshold(1);`, 
i.e. Default value for prepareThreshold.
The result was the same.

Then I tried the java program with "set enable_nestloop false" as the first line of the stored procedure and it completes in 4 minutes.

I am not able to understand why the query changes the execution plan, when I am explicitly forcing server side prepared statement.

I am using Postgres 9.4 and Java 8. I am also using PGBouncer for connection pooling.

My query here is - Why is JDBC influencing the execution plan if at all? Is there a way to force server side execution plan to my query triggered from java program?

Comment: How many rows does it return? And what exactly does the function `x` do? Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the code for the function `x`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It does not return anything. It is a stored procedure which performs a few joins and loads data into another table. The conditions are the same when I execute the query from stored procedure and when I execute it using JDBC.

Comment: Are you sure that you execute it on same database?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is on the same database.I can see it on the server status and in the table pg_stat_activity. The query is the same in both cases.

Comment: What's the purpose of `pgstmt.setPrepareThreshold(1)`?

Comment: BTW you are using prepared statement in incorrect way: your "`myParameter`" should be passed as parameter, i.e. ":myParameter" and set up it using `statement.set...()`.

Comment: I have even tried it without pgstmt.setPrepareThreshold(1) with the same result. I researched a bit about execution plan getting changed on executing from JDBC and was led to the link https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/server-prepare.html . I have successfully executed another stored procedure by passing the parameter in the same way. Hence, I am sure it is not related to the way I passed my parameters.

Comment: I am using postgres 9.4, java 8

Comment: I was trying a lot of things. This was just the last thing that I tried. I believe the prepared statement part is wrong on my part. Thanks for pointing it out @Kayaman. I am sorry for going astray. Now I used the documentation for 9.4 https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/server-prepare.html modified my java code and executed it. The result is still the same.

Comment: Install [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html), add it to `session_preload_libraries`, set `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` in `postgresql.conf` and reload the database server. Then call the function from `psql` and from your Java program and compare the execution plans you find in the PostgreSQL log. This information will help understand what's going on.

Comment: @Laurenz- since my java program executes fine with enable_nestloop set to false, I can say that there is a difference in the execution plan when executed from JDBC as compared to when executed from pgadmin. This issue is coming only in a production machine, where I cannot install auto_explain. Moreover, there may be many such stored procedures, all of which will be executed in the same way, I want to find if there is any way to enforce server side execution plan to my java program. This particular stored proc has been resolved by disabling nestloop.

Comment: I am ok with 4 minutes. The stored procedure performs a number of joins of tables of sizes 3-20 GB performs a few groups and write it to another table. Hence, 4 minutes is acceptable. My problem is the same procedure when executed in Java is taking different time. We have another team writing the stored procedures. They want the execution from Java to be the same as independent execution. Hence server side prepared statement. I am open to any suggestion which can guarantee my Java program uses the same execution plan as when executed from pgadmin(On server).

Comment: Yes. It takes 26 hours with and without server side prepared statements. I set threshold to 1 prepare the statement on server side. I just wanted to show that it had been tried out because when I researched on this topic, I found the answers directing to use server side prepare statements.

Comment: I concede that I might be wrong in my use. But it is just a part of a few things to try it out. My original code included only the first and the last line of the java snippet I shared in the question. I reiterate- My problem is different execution plan when executed using Java(JDBC). Is there any way that I can guarantee my query executed using java program uses the same execution plan as when executed directly at the server.

Answer (score 4):

**Got the solution:-**
There is a table used within the stored procedure say "tab1".

When we run stored procedure from PGAdmin/SQL window tab1 is already created/modified hours back.

In the automated running, using java, tab1 is created and loaded/modified just seconds before the execution of the stored procedure.
In the first case(*Running stored procedure from PGAdmin/SQL window*)  auto-analyze on tab1 has finished by the time we run the stored procedure in PGAdmin, whereas in the second case(*automated running using java*) auto-analyze on tab1  is yet to start or is under process as the tab1 has just been modified .

This causes Postgres to choose a better plan at the time of running the query from PGAdmin, as compared to the time when we run using java.

Summary- Different plans were chosen because In the second case, auto-analyze did not complete by the time we ran the stored proc, resulting in a poor query plan selection.